# Generate Sequence number for nested loops for xsl transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform the input xml through xsl. I want to generate the Book numbers in nested loop but `Position()` function only returns value of the node inside the inner loop. Using xslt 2.0

made the input well formed

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:z="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
<Library>
    <LibraryName>Berlin Central Library</LibraryName>
    <Books>
        <BookName>Harry Potter</BookName>
    </Books>
    <Books>
        <BookName>Lord of the Rings</BookName>
    </Books>
</Library>
<Library>
<LibraryName>London Central Library</LibraryName>
    <Books>
    <BookName>The alchemist</BookName>
    </Books>
    <Books>
    <BookName>The detective</BookName>
    </Books>
</Library>
<Library>
<LibraryName>Delhi Central Library</LibraryName>
    <Books>
    <BookName>The Discovery of India</BookName>
    </Books>
</Library>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output expected:

```
<Book>
    <Library Name>Berlin Central Library</Library Name>
    <Book Number>1</Book Number>
    <Book Name>Harry Potter</Book Name>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Library Name>Berlin Central Library</Library Name>
    <Book Number>2</Book Number>
    <Book Name>Lord of the Rings</Book Name>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Library Name>London Central Library</Library Name>
    <Book Number>3</Book Number>
    <Book Name>The alchemist</Book Name>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Library Name>London Central Library</Library Name>
    <Book Number>4</Book Number>
    <Book Name>The detective</Book Name>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Library Name>Delhi Central Library</Library Name>
    <Book Number>5</Book Number>
    <Book Name>The Discovery of India</Book Name>
</Book>
```

Comment: `<Book Number>4</Book Number>` is not even a well-formed XML element markup. Neither are `Library Name` or `Book Name`. If your nested `loop` doesn't give you the result with `position()`, why can't you just process the `Books` element directly?

Comment: made the input well formed. Created this sample as cant share original xml. in books element. Position function resets eg."the detective" will have the book number as 2 instead of needed 4

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nested loops". Posted an answer based on guess. Next time post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you could approach this, given a **well-formed** input of:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <Library>
        <LibraryName>Berlin Central Library</LibraryName>
        <Books>
            <BookName>Harry Potter</BookName>
        </Books>
        <Books>
            <BookName>Lord of the Rings</BookName>
        </Books>
    </Library>
    <Library>
    <LibraryName>London Central Library</LibraryName>
        <Books>
        <BookName>The alchemist</BookName>
        </Books>
        <Books>
        <BookName>The detective</BookName>
        </Books>
    </Library>
    <Library>
    <LibraryName>Delhi Central Library</LibraryName>
        <Books>
        <BookName>The Discovery of India</BookName>
        </Books>
    </Library>
</root>
```

**XSLT option 1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Library/Books">
            <Book>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../LibraryName"/>
                <BookNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </BookNumber>
                <xsl:copy-of select="BookName"/>
            </Book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT option 2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Library">
            <xsl:variable name="lib" select="LibraryName"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Books">
                <Book>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$lib"/>
                    <BookNumber>
                        <xsl:number level="any"/>
                    </BookNumber>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="BookName"/>
                </Book>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```